# How to measure the electrical properties to ensure the performance of a thin electrode/insulator stack-up?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, measurements, consumer-electronics

I am a mechanical engineer by trade, and I am looking at some basic electrical properties that I need to measure to ensure the device meets the desired performance. The device consists of a two-layer stack up consisting of a 100 nm electrode underneath a 500 nm dielectric layer. There are several electrodes that need to operate independently (so, they need to be isolated electrically from each other, and also not capacitively coupled due to close proximity), and the dielectric layer needs to withstand electric leakage/dielectric breakdown.

What would be the best ways to measure each of these?

Comment: This is a solved problem in the world of integrated circuit chip manufacture- specifically, in the area of what is called thin film technology. Entire engineering classes are taught on this very subject- just not to mechanical engineers, but to EE's who are learning device physics and IC manufacture.

This is far too broad a topic to cover here, so I recommend you team up with a IC process engineer who works in a wafer fab facility. They can show you the ropes.

Comment: I am really not looking for a detailed explanation, but more for some keywords for characterizing techniques that can point me in the right direction to self-learn. For e.g., if someone asked me ways to measure surface topography, I would mention "Profilometer/AFM/White Light Interferometer etc.".
Unfortunately, I don't have access to IC engineers, so any books/websites/MOOCs would also be helpful.